# Sum values in specific columns in DataFrame and ignore None

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the distance that my cars have driven. I have all the coordinates that the cars need to go to. Some cars parks earlier then others, and this messes up my calculation.
I have this:

```
cars= pd.DataFrame({'x': [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                        'y': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
                        'x_goal_1': [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                        'y_goal_1': [10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10],
                        'x_goal_2': [17,24,31,31,17,17,38,38,31],
                        'y_goal_2': [10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10],
                        'x_goal_3': [17,24,31,31,17,17,38,38,31],
                        'y_goal_3': [17, 3, 3, 3, 17, 17, 17, 17, 3],
                        'x_goal_4': [None,27,35,28,14,18,42,43,None],
                        'y_goal_4': [None, 3, 3, 3, 17, 17, 17, 17, None],
                        'z': [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,22]})
 
    cars['moved_tot'] = (
                        abs(cars['x']-cars['x_goal_1']) + abs(cars['y']-cars['y_goal_1']) +
                        abs(cars['x_goal_1']-cars['x_goal_2']) + abs(cars['y_goal_1']-cars['y_goal_2']) +
                        abs(cars['x_goal_2']-cars['x_goal_3']) + abs(cars['y_goal_2']-cars['y_goal_3']) +
                        abs(cars['x_goal_3']-cars['x_goal_4']) + abs(cars['y_goal_3']-cars['y_goal_4']) )
```

I then get:

```
   x  y  x_goal_1  y_goal_1  ...  x_goal_4  y_goal_4   z  moved_tot
0  3  1         3        10  ...       NaN       NaN   3        NaN
1  3  2         3        10  ...      27.0       3.0   4       39.0
2  3  3         3        10  ...      35.0       3.0   5       46.0
3  3  4         3        10  ...      28.0       3.0   6       44.0
4  3  5         3        10  ...      14.0      17.0   7       29.0
5  3  6         3        10  ...      18.0      17.0   8       26.0
6  3  7         3        10  ...      42.0      17.0   9       49.0
7  3  8         3        10  ...      43.0      17.0  12       49.0
8  3  9         3        10  ...       NaN       NaN  22        NaN
```

I want the first moved_tot I want 30, and in the last I want 36. I want the calculation to ignore if a value is None ( that is if this car has parked earlier ). How do I do this?

with help from David S ( thank you! )  I figured out how to do it.

```
bags['moved_tot'] = (
                    abs(bags['x']-bags['x_goal_1']).fillna(0) + abs(bags['y']-bags['y_goal_1']).fillna(0) +
                    abs(bags['x_goal_1']-bags['x_goal_2']).fillna(0) + abs(bags['y_goal_1']-bags['y_goal_2']).fillna(0) +
                    abs(bags['x_goal_2']-bags['x_goal_3']).fillna(0) + abs(bags['y_goal_2']-bags['y_goal_3']).fillna(0) +
                    abs(bags['x_goal_3']-bags['x_goal_4']).fillna(0) + abs(bags['y_goal_3']-bags['y_goal_4']).fillna(0) 
                    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just replace the `NaN` inplace with `0` to avoid getting `NaN` in the result column, like:

```
cars['moved_tot'] = (abs(cars['x']-cars['x_goal_1'].fillna(0)) + abs(cars['y']-cars['y_goal_1'].fillna(0)) +
                        abs(cars['x_goal_1'].fillna(0)-cars['x_goal_2'].fillna(0)) + abs(cars['y_goal_1'].fillna(0)-cars['y_goal_2'].fillna(0)) +
                        abs(cars['x_goal_2'].fillna(0)-cars['x_goal_3'].fillna(0)) + abs(cars['y_goal_2'].fillna(0)-cars['y_goal_3'].fillna(0)) +
                        abs(cars['x_goal_3'].fillna(0)-cars['x_goal_4'].fillna(0)) + abs(cars['y_goal_3'].fillna(0)-cars['y_goal_4'].fillna(0)) )
```

If you want to `0` the calculation result if `NaN` is present just move the `.fillna(0)` to outside the `abs()`

Comment: It then calculates as if it had the coordinate 0 and adds the distance to this coordinate, and the car has not driven to 0, it has only stoppt.

Comment: When I write the fillna(0) outside the () it works...  abs(bags['x']-bags['x_goal_1']).fillna(0) it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `cars = cars.fillna(0)` or `cars.fillna(0, inplace=True)` to get rid of repeating `.fillna(0)` after each `abs`.

If you don't want to change the original dataframe, use `cars_ = cars.fillna(0)` then replace `cars` in `cars['moved_tot']` to `cars_`.

Besides, you could make use of the feature of columns to get rid of writing repeating column names.

```py
cars_ = cars.fillna(0)

cars_['moved_tot'] = 0
for i in range(len(cars.columns) - 3):
    print(cars_.columns[i], '-', cars_.columns[i+2])
    cars_['moved_tot'] += abs(cars_[cars_.columns[i]] - cars_[cars_.columns[i+2]])
```

```
# Output and print(cars_)

x - x_goal_1
y - y_goal_1
x_goal_1 - x_goal_2
y_goal_1 - y_goal_2
x_goal_2 - x_goal_3
y_goal_2 - y_goal_3
x_goal_3 - x_goal_4
y_goal_3 - y_goal_4

   x  y  x_goal_1  y_goal_1  x_goal_2  y_goal_2  x_goal_3  y_goal_3  x_goal_4  y_goal_4   z  moved_tot
0  3  1         3        10        17        10        17        17       0.0       0.0   3       64.0
1  3  2         3        10        24        10        24         3      27.0       3.0   4       39.0
2  3  3         3        10        31        10        31         3      35.0       3.0   5       46.0
3  3  4         3        10        31        10        31         3      28.0       3.0   6       44.0
4  3  5         3        10        17        10        17        17      14.0      17.0   7       29.0
5  3  6         3        10        17        10        17        17      18.0      17.0   8       26.0
6  3  7         3        10        38        10        38        17      42.0      17.0   9       49.0
7  3  8         3        10        38        10        38        17      43.0      17.0  12       49.0
8  3  9         3        10        31        10        31         3       0.0       0.0  22       70.0
```

You could even do the sum in one line

```py
cars_['moved_tot'] = pd.concat([abs(cars_[cars_.columns[i]] - cars_[cars_.columns[i+2]]) for i in range(len(cars.columns) - 3)], axis=1).sum(1)
```